# Integer solutions of an exponential equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

How can I solve this equation?

$$7^{x} +2=y^{2}$$

$x$ and $y$ must be natural numbers.

Comment: This is remarkably close in form to the Ramanujan-Nadell equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Nagell_equation , and is indeed covered by the theory of equations of Ramanujan-Nadell type, as discussed in that link.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A general method, not necessarily best for this particular equation, is to split into three cases by writing $x=3u+v$ with $v\in\{0,1,2\}$. Then rewrite your equation as
$$ A(7^u)^3 + 2 = y^2\quad\text{with $A\in\{1,7,49\}$.} $$
So any solution to your equation gives an integer solution to one of the three equations
$$ w^3+2=y^2,\quad 7w^3+2=y^2,\quad49w^3+2=y^2.$$
There are then standard methods for finding integer points on these genus $1$ curves.

**Addendum**: You can use the LMFDB to finish the solution. I'll rewrite the curves using the more typical $x,y$ variables.
For $y^2=x^3+2$, we see from http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/1728/n/4 that the curve has rank $1$ and the only integer solutions are $(-1,\pm1)$, which don't result in roots for your equation.
For $7w^3+2=y^2$, we multiply by $7^2$ and change coordinates to get the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+98$. Then http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/28224/dp/2 says that the rank is $1$, and the only integer points are $(7,\pm21)$, which gives the solution $7^1+2=(\pm3)^2$.
And for $49w^3+2=y^2$, we multiply by $7^4$ and change coordinates to get the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3+4802$. Then
http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/84672/fl/2 tells us that this curve has rank $0$ and no integer points. Hence your original equation $7^x+2=y^2$ has only the solutions $(x,y)=(1,\pm3)$.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a proof that the $x=1$ solution is unique
using only facts about "Pell equations" that were already known to Fermat
(if not centuries earlier to Bhaskara II et al.)
and should generalize at least to $p^x + 2 = y^2$
for odd primes $p$ such that $p+2$ is a square.
I'll simplify the formulas by using $\sqrt 7$ (more generally, $\sqrt p$).

We start by observing that $x$ must be odd; this can be seen
in various ways, for example by reducing $\bmod 4$.  So, $7^x = 7 z^2$
where $z = 7^{(x-1)/2}$, and we seek solutions of $y^2 - 7 z^2 = 2$
where $z$ is a power of $7$.  Now the general solution of $y^2 - 7z^2 = 2$
in natural numbers $y,z$ is $(y_n,z_n)$ such that
$$
y_n + z_n \sqrt7 = \alpha u^n \quad (n \geq 0)
$$
where $\alpha = 3+\sqrt 7$ and $u$ is the fundamental unit
$\alpha / \bar\alpha = 8 + 3\sqrt 7$.  (Note that this gives
$y_n - z_n \sqrt 7 = \alpha u^{-(n+1)}$, so the solutions coming from $n < 0$
only repeat those with $n \geq 0$.)  Now if $x > 1$ then $7 \mid z$,
which happens if and only if $7 \mid 2n+1$.  But then $z_n$ is a multiple of
$z_3 = 7 \cdot 617$, and $617$ is not a multiple of $7$.
Therefore $z_n$ is never a power of $7$ other than 1, **QED**.

(Alternatively, having found the condition $7 \mid 2n+1$ for $7 \mid z_n$,
we could continue by asking when $7^2 \mid z_n$, $\ 7^3 \mid z_n$,
etc., finding that $7^e | z_n$ if and only if $7^e | 2n+1$,
and then $z_n \geq z_{(7^e-1)/2}$ which is much larger than $7^e$.)